# Cannot find module 'dotenv' even though is it installed and typescript is configured

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, dotenv, typescript-module-resolution

Yes, I know it's a very basic problem and that there are plenty of questions like this. But none sounds to be exactly the same as my case and I just can't wrap my mind around this issue. So here I go, I have the following files:

`src/main.ts`

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
console.log("JWT_SALT", process.env.JWT_SALT);
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "family-budget-control",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The back of of the Family Budget Control application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start-watch": "gulp",
    "compile": "npx tsc",
    "start": "npx tsc && node compiled/main.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "davincif",
  "license": "Zlib",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "del": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.5.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",

    "module": "ES6",

    "outDir": "compiled",

    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,

    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "compiled", "dist"]
}
```

But when running npm run compile, or npx tsc directly, I get this:

```
src/main.ts:1:20 - error TS2792: Cannot find module 'dotenv'. Did you
mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases
to the 'paths' option?
 
1 import dotenv from "dotenv";
```

- Yes, everyting **is** installed;
- No, I **can't** use request();
- No npm install --dotenv-extended didn't work.

I honestly feel I'm missing out something really obvious, but can't figure it out. Any help?

Comment: have you tried the `moduleResolution` as its mention in the error

Comment: Omg... I knew I was missing something obvious. That did it. Thank you =)